# web-application got halted when call the stored procedure several time using spring-mybatis 1.2 & spring 3.1.1

Tags: spring, spring-mybatis

I trying to use the stored procedure, and web-application is halted when I call the procedure several time. It stopped when opening the JDBC connection. is mybatis-spring has a problem when insert statement?

I've call the stored procedure that is update the table and if it can't find the target row, just insert the new row. But, when I call the procedure several time, web-application is halted and all of the DB connection isn't established. I've trying to change the db-context bean. But, it still not working.

my db-context.xml is set following below.

-->

```
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref="repositoryDataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/config/mybatis/mybatis-config.xml" />
    <property name="mapperLocations" value="/WEB-INF/config/mybatis/mapper/*.xml" />
    <property name="databaseIdProvider" ref="databaseIdProvider" />
</bean>

<bean id="vendorProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="SQL Server">sqlserver</prop>
            <prop key="DB2">db2</prop>
            <prop key="Oracle">oracle</prop>
            <prop key="MySQL">mysql</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="databaseIdProvider" class="org.apache.ibatis.mapping.VendorDatabaseIdProvider">
    <property name="properties" ref="vendorProperties" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSessionTemplate" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate" destroy-method="clearCache">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

The logs at the bottom are the logs that worked.

```
    DEBUG [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] Creating a new SqlSession 
    DEBUG [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@6d896e0a] was not registered for synchronization because synchronization is not active 
    DEBUG [org.apache.ibatis.transaction.managed.ManagedTransaction] Opening JDBC Connection 
    DEBUG [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@6d896e0a] 
    DEBUG [org.apache.ibatis.transaction.managed.ManagedTransaction] Closing JDBC Connection [jdbc:sqlserver://serverIP:PORT;authenticationScheme=nativeAuthentication;xopenStates=false;sendTimeAsDatetime=true;trustServerCertificate=false;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=true;selectMethod=direct;responseBuffering=adaptive;packetSize=8000;multiSubnetFailover=false;loginTimeout=15;lockTimeout=-1;lastUpdateCount=true;encrypt=false;disableStatementPooling=true;databaseName=testDataBaseName;applicationName=Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server;applicationIntent=readwrite;, UserName=user, Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server] 
    DEBUG [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] Creating a new SqlSession 
    DEBUG [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@3d4bdd0f] was not registered for synchronization because synchronization is not active 
    DEBUG [org.apache.ibatis.transaction.managed.ManagedTransaction] Opening JDBC Connection 
    DEBUG [Report.CALL_UP_SP] ==>  Preparing: {call CALL_UP_SP ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )}  
    DEBUG [Report.CALL_UP_SP] ==> Parameters: 0(Integer), 19277(String), saveName(String), 2261(String), PUBLIC(String), 370(String), someString(String), (String), (String), (String), (String), (String), (String), (String), someString(String), someString(String), someString(String), someString(String), PFBBUkFNX1hNTC8+(String), (String), 1000(String), N(String), N(String), (String), 1000(String), N(String) 
    DEBUG [Report.CALL_UP_SP] <==      Total: 1 
    DEBUG [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@3d4bdd0f] 
    DEBUG [org.apache.ibatis.transaction.managed.ManagedTransaction] Closing JDBC Connection [jdbc:sqlserver://serverIP:PORT;authenticationScheme=nativeAuthentication;xopenStates=false;sendTimeAsDatetime=true;trustServerCertificate=false;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=true;selectMethod=direct;responseBuffering=adaptive;packetSize=8000;multiSubnetFailover=false;loginTimeout=15;lockTimeout=-1;lastUpdateCount=true;encrypt=false;disableStatementPooling=true;databaseName=testDataBaseName;applicationName=Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server;applicationIntent=readwrite;, UserName=user, Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server]
```

And I attaching it broken down log.

```
    DEBUG [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] Creating a new SqlSession 
    DEBUG [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@25f74881] was not registered for synchronization because synchronization is not active 
    DEBUG [org.apache.ibatis.transaction.managed.ManagedTransaction] Opening JDBC Connection 
    DEBUG [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@25f74881] 
    DEBUG [org.apache.ibatis.transaction.managed.ManagedTransaction] Closing JDBC Connection [jdbc:sqlserver://serverIP:PORT;authenticationScheme=nativeAuthentication;xopenStates=false;sendTimeAsDatetime=true;trustServerCertificate=false;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=true;selectMethod=direct;responseBuffering=adaptive;packetSize=8000;multiSubnetFailover=false;loginTimeout=15;lockTimeout=-1;lastUpdateCount=true;encrypt=false;disableStatementPooling=true;databaseName=testDataBaseName;applicationName=Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server;applicationIntent=readwrite;, UserName=user, Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server] 
    DEBUG [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] Creating a new SqlSession 
    DEBUG [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@18d75584] was not registered for synchronization because synchronization is not active 
    DEBUG [org.apache.ibatis.transaction.managed.ManagedTransaction] Opening JDBC Connection (--> web-application doesn't work after it)
```

As you see, org.apache.ibatis.transaction.managed.ManagedTransaction is opening the JDBC Connection, but it dosent work after.
So, I tried restart the tomcat 7, following log is presented on eclipse console.

```
    The web application [/test] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@14d49cb3]) and a value of type [org.apache.ibatis.executor.ErrorContext] (value [
    ### The error may exist in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/mybatis/mapper/test.xml]
    ### The error may involve test.CALL_UP_SP
    ### The error occurred while executing a query]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

Anybody knows this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It's not a problem at the calling procedure. In my case, I have to handle the various DBMS. So, I have to check the DBMS type for handle it. But, for the check the DBMS, I wrote down the code following like below.

```
DBMSName = super.getSqlSession().getConfiguration().getEnvironment().getDataSource().getConnection().getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName();
System.out.println("current DBMS type : "+DBMSName);
```

In this case, I think it open the connection until web-application stop. So, I remove the code and It works fine. Anybody know why it happens?